# "show n more comments" grabs focus, kills cursor keys

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, scrolling, focus

Clicking on "[add /] show *n* more comments" grabs the focus, placing it in the newly revealed add comment field. This prevents cursor keys from scrolling, which is driving me up the wall. Probably only significant if using a non-Apple trackpad/touchscreen*.

If you haven't seen all the comments, I think it's inappropriate to have any kind of commitment to adding a comment. So perhaps the "add /" could be removed, with the usual "add comment" appearing once expanded.

(*My Mac screen is broken, so now using a touchscreen netbook [rubberised Latitude 2100] with standard bad PC trackpad (two-finger scrolling is vomit inducing).)

Comment: +1 - Just noticed this today, and I wonder if it's new.  I never had an issue with it previously.

Comment: Serious agree with "why are the add comment and show all comments features attached to one button". That's never made sense to me.

Comment: I'll bet this could be fixed quickly with a userscript, but I'm way too swamped to try this now. Does this netbook run Chrome?

Comment: This causes the keyboard on the iPad's browser to pop up, obscuring a lot of the screen. Silly me, I'd thought this was an iOS 5 issue.

Comment: @The Unhandled Exception Of course I'm running Chrome! (Not Chrome OS. (Xubuntu since normal Ununtu was ruined.))

Comment: Great idea - when there are hidden comments, we'll not focus the textarea on display.

Answer (score 6):

Under the assumption that people want to read first before commenting, from the next build on, we'll only auto-focus the box if all comments were there already.