# Add/Show comments focuses text box by default

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, mobile-web

If I open a post using the mobile theme, which has many comments, there is a link at the footer "add/show n more comments". If this link is clicked, the comments are loaded and displayed.

At the moment the text area is automatically focused which is not a great experience (in my opinion), as you have to close the editor and scroll back to the top if you just wanted to read the comments, without adding a new one.

Would it be possible to either

- not focus the text area by default and to load only the comments
- add a new link for adding a comment

Comment: I'll have to check on my mobile device sometime (Droid Pro), but it doesn't strike me that this is what happens when I click that link on a post with lots of comments. I could just be misremembering, I suppose... but I think that would bug me, too.

Comment: +1, reproduced on Droid X2.  I find this annoying, but didn't think to post about it =)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111697/show-n-more-comments-grabs-focus-kills-cursor-keys (this one's about the standard theme, which also has this problem).

Comment: As the text-box is focussed it also has the annoying side-effect of popping up the virtual keyboard on my Xoom and Galaxy S, covering up half the screen, and meaning I have to close the keyboard to see all the comments that I've un-hidden.

Comment: @Laura, as the above is status-completed, I guess so is [“add/show X comments” link on mobile scrolls, zooms and opens keyboard](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225947/add-show-x-comments-link-on-mobile-scrolls-zooms-and-opens-keyboard)? (Which I feel is still a dupe, but for some reason Tim Post reopened that one, some time ago.)

Comment: @Arjan, [my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225947/add-show-x-comments-link-on-mobile-scrolls-zooms-and-opens-keyboard) was re-opened because this "duplicate" did not have a posted solution.  That is explained in my last edit.  However, since that time, the mobile version has been completely re-worked so that this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 22):

EDIT: Yay, [as of 25 July 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266815), there is an "Show X more comment(s)" link next to "Add comment".

---

Please remove autofocus from the input field. As seen in the screencast below, autofocus on mobile degrades the UX of the ones who want to read comments on their phone.

After tapping "Show more comments", the input field is focused (and my keyboard pops up). 
Because of the small screen, it takes a few seconds to drag the screen back to its previous position.

[image]

Comment: +1 A thousand times this. I actually just came here to ask this.