# Consider iSomethings in UI design

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, mobile-web, usability, iphone

I almost exclusively use an iPhone to post. There are some aspects of the site that are range from awkward to impossible to use.

Can some work be done to cater for iSomething users to make it friendlier?

Note that I use the site in full mode - the mobile version lacks bells and whistles I commonly use.

Here's a list of some of the issues I have found:

- Formatting buttons of answer input area should be moved one line up above the top of the input area, because on an iSomething, when you highlight text, you get an action popup above the highlighted text (that says `Cut Copy Paste`), which when obscures the buttons if the highlight is on the first line
- maybe asking for too much, but commonly used code characters are on the secondary or tertiary keyboard, and some very commonly needed characters like the backtick are hidden behind press-and-hold. Further compounding the problem is that the keyboard reverts to standard when pressing space, so I am constantly pressing the alternate keyboard button. We can't fix the iPhone keyboard, but can we have something like an (optional) set of symbol buttons, perhaps positioned under the formatting buttons, of these characters `()[]<>{}'"|&@` and the back tick and maybe the numbers too
- chat is almost unusable. On the mobile site you can't zoom it, so unless you eyesight is very good, text is illegible. On the full site, zoom is possible, but the right hand nav panel rapidly flows to completely cover the main part of the screen, making reading and sending messages very difficult

I could keep going with other usability issues if requested.

I have used the site on an iPad too, but only rarely, so I can't say whether all the issues I have with the iPhone are also found on iPads, however I suspect they would be.

---

p.s. The winter bash hat positioner is impossible to use, because mouse drag is impossible for me. Better would be four arrow buttons that shift the hat - maybe next year

Comment: `The winter bash hat positioner is impossible to use, because mouse drag is impossible for me. Better would be four arrow buttons that shift the hat` - a fix for this will be deployed is 1 hour and 29 minutes. :-)

Comment: Note that a iOS native client is in the works; I cannot imagine the SE team putting much effort in the mobile version just for iSomething devices while that is in the pipeline.

Comment: @psubsee2003 can a fix be rushed out in time just for me (the only one who cares about it) before winter bash ends?

Comment: @Bohemian: See the 'I hate hats' checkbox? We put that there *just now*, **just for you**. :-P

Comment: Apparently Apple is the only manufacturer of mobile devices in the world...?

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow I don't have an android, so I don't know if they have these issues.

Answer (score 6):

> Note that I use the site in full mode - the mobile version lacks bells and whistles I commonly use.

So request changes to the mobile version then. It *exists* to resolve UI issues with using the full site on mobile devices!

Or wait for the iOS app to enter public beta (or at least invite-only alpha).

Issues with the full theme on the iPad may be warranted (IIRC, you get the full design by default there), but it is explicitly *not* customized for tiny screens. Some features are missing *because* cramming them onto a small screen would make everything hard to use. Them's the breaks.

Comment: Hey... who are you calling "tiny"!?

Comment: Wait, we're talking about tablet issues? Oh man, would I love to see a change like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117351/add-show-comments-focuses-text-box-by-default), so my soft keyboard stops assaulting me...

Comment: Pretty sure that's annoying as hell on ALL mobile devices, @Michael.

Comment: Yeah. My comment was pointing at the wrong post, though. The issue was introduced a few months ago, stemming from [this bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208901/clicking-on-add-comment-used-to-focus-on-the-comment-area-but-it-doesnt-anymo) (I *think* it had worked as I'd expected for a good long time before then). What I'm looking for, I suppose, is a special case in the standard theme for tablets, blocking focus. Anyway, this is a bit of a hijack.