# "add/show X comments" link on mobile scrolls, zooms and opens keyboard

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, mobile-web

On the mobile-web version of Stack Exchange sites, clicking the "add / show X more comments" link always zooms the "new comment" field into focus and opens the keyboard.  It also scrolls the page towards the top a bit so the new comments appear off the bottom of the screen.

Most of the time, when clicking on that link, I just want to read the hidden comments.  It's annoying when I have to dismiss the keyboard, zoom out and scroll back.

It should simply reveal the new comments and the keyboard should not show up unless I decide to tap inside the "new comment" field.

This is observed with the latest version of Mobile Safari in the latest iOS, although it's likely an issue on all mobile devices whenever the mobile version is displayed.

---

**EDIT:**

This question was closed with this reason:

> *"This question has been asked before and already has an answer. **If those answers do not fully address your question**, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question."*

However, the original question **does not already have an answer** with a solution nor even an explanation. [The posted answer is just another complaint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212234/157574) like mine.

I don't dispute that I accidently posted the same complaint.  However, based on the wording of the closed reason, it would seem to imply that duplicates are allowed in situations when the original does *"not fully address"* the question.

Comment: Same behavior on android 4.1, GS3, Firefox. Quite annoying.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName, that's the same complaint, but FWIW it's a two-year-old [tag:feature-request] without a resolution.  I'll argue this is really a [tag:bug] and badly needs a fix.

Comment: I agree that it badly needs fixing, but the appropriate action is placing a bounty rather than reposting.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName, feel free to place that bounty. My initial search failed to reveal the two-year-old posting so this was a purely unintentional duplicate. However, if somebody in authority really cares about getting this fixed, it doesn't matter if/when my question gets closed or deleted.

Comment: Regarding the down-vote:  Does somebody really think this isn't a bug or that the current behavior is preferred over getting it fixed?

Comment: @Sparky not my downvote, but only 1 vs. 9 upvotes... really minor. Personally I do agree it's a dupe of the original request so maybe someone thinking same way was more "aggressive".

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I'm not upset about the down-vote at all and I agree with your assessment.  Just very curious about the motivation... wondering if somebody _really_ does think the reported behavior is preferred.  After all, it's not been fixed since reported a couple years ago, so _maybe_ this behavior is intentional.  Otherwise, if we all agree that this is a bug, why not just fix it?

Comment: @Sparky it all boils down to behavior that works fine on desktop browser and misbehaves on mobile device, I won't call it a bug really. But yes, I agree that changing the behavior in the mobile theme will improve the user experience, hence I upvoted that feature request. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I understand.  However, I could make an argument that the behavior on the desktop version, although much less annoying, is no less a bug (or let's say mis-programmed).  After all, do we really need the field automatically coming into focus, desktop or not, when simply wanting to read hidden comments?

Comment: Oh yes... I'm really used to it auto focusing and so are many others. When I click "add comment" I expect it to be auto focused. At some point it was broken and [reported as a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208901/152859).

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I prefer to read the existing comments before deciding if I'm going to add one myself.  Certainly, there's a solution to make this work properly on both platforms.

Comment: I've upvoted this and the old post as well, however I can see the point Shadow Wizard made. I personally operate as Sparky said; to see existing comments first before deciding whether to add one, etc. However, I think we can surmise there are more than a few people who operate like Shadow Wizard, and want the comment box ready to receive input as early as possible. Consequently, they can still choose not to leave a comment ultimately, and the worst that happens is people like Sparky and I have to zoom out and scroll. Its bloody annoying, but maybe its the lesser of two evils?

Comment: @PaulRichter, I am not advocating that whatever fix is implemented that it necessarily be forced upon desktop users.  Since a different theme is in place for mobile users, it stands to reason that it can be fixed for mobile without breaking the desktop version.

Comment: @Sparky Yeah that's reasonable, and likely possible, depending on how its all implemented (ultimately I don't see why not). I wasn't referring to the desktop version though, I was talking only about mobile theme. Maybe I misunderstood Shadow Wizard's and your last statements, I thought you both were also referring to mobile; sorry if I got mixed up. Anyways, long story short, in regards to the mobile version, I agree with your suggestion.

Comment: Given the Concerns on current usability vs. Target usability, would it be an alternative to split the button up into different ones??

Comment: @Vogel612 I'm not convinced that's the _best_ solution, however, it's still far better than what we have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime since this question was posted, SE has entirely re-designed the mobile version.

Now there are two links, one to post a comment and another one to view more comments.  Therefore this bug has been eliminated.